# To merge two XMLs with common fields using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have two xmls

1. `a.xml`
2. `b.xml`

Below is the `a.xml` file

```
<ConsumerKeyperUsers>

    <CONSUMERKEY_1>
        <CONSUMERKEY>QoChiX5FlNyqe1FuqU7VB2M</CONSUMERKEY>
    </CONSUMERKEY_1>
    <CONSUMERKEY_2>
        <CONSUMERKEY>uzGjRVxnxmP00zrnZPtB9sM</CONSUMERKEY>
    </CONSUMERKEY_2>
    <CONSUMERKEY_3>
        <CONSUMERKEY>RD37oO2jg4rlerxW5p6f76</CONSUMERKEY>
    </CONSUMERKEY_3>

</ConsumerKeyperUsers>
```

and below is the b.xml

```
<Details>

<Detail>
<ConsumeyKey>QoChiX5FlNyqe1FuqU7VB2M</ConsumeyKey>
<Place>Ocean</Place>
<City>Urban</City>
</Detail>

<Detail>
<ConsumeyKey>uzGjRVxnxmP00zrnZPtB9sM</ConsumeyKey>
<Place>Road</Place>
<City>Rural</City>
</Detail>

<Detail>
<ConsumeyKey>RD37oO2jg4rlerxW5p6f76</ConsumeyKey>
<Place>Plane</Place>
<City>Semiurban</City>
</Detail>

<Detail>
<ConsumeyKey>likujyhtasasa</ConsumeyKey>
<Place>Ship</Place>
<City>Semirural</City>
</Detail>

</Details>
```

Now, I want to get the output somewhat like below

```
    <ConsumerKeyperUsers>

    <CONSUMERKEY_1>
    <CONSUMERKEY>QoChiX5FlNyqe1FuqU7VB2M</CONSUMERKEY>
    <Place>Ocean</Place>
    <City>Urban</City>
    </CONSUMERKEY_1>

    <CONSUMERKEY_2>
    <CONSUMERKEY>uzGjRVxnxmP00zrnZPtB9sM</CONSUMERKEY>
    <Place>Road</Place>
    <City>Rural</City>
    </CONSUMERKEY_2>

    <CONSUMERKEY_3>
    <CONSUMERKEY>RD37oO2jg4rlerxW5p6f76</CONSUMERKEY>
    <Place>Plane</Place>
    <City>Semiurban</City>
    </CONSUMERKEY_3>

    </ConsumerKeyperUsers>
```

I am pretty new in xslt. Any xslt version would be ok to use.

Besides, I also want to know how to feed these two xml to the xslt. Do we have to store it in server where xslt can access these files.

Any guidance in this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want to know how to feed these two xml to the xslt.

Tell your application to process the `a.xml` file, and pass the path to `b.xml` as a parameter.

Use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) to lookup the data from `b.xml` - for example (untested):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="file2" select="'b.xml'" />
<xsl:key name="details" match="Detail" use="ConsumeyKey" />

<xsl:template match="/ConsumerKeyperUsers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="CONSUMERKEY"/>
                <xsl:variable name="details" select="key('details', CONSUMERKEY, document($file2))" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$details/Place"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$details/City"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To do the same thing using an XSLT 1.0 processor is slightly more complicated:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="file2" select="'b.xml'" />
<xsl:key name="details" match="Detail" use="ConsumeyKey" />

<xsl:template match="/ConsumerKeyperUsers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:variable name="key" select="CONSUMERKEY" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$key"/>
                <!--  switch context to file2 in order to use key -->
                <xsl:for-each select="document($file2)">
                    <xsl:variable name="details" select="key('details', $key)" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$details/Place"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$details/City"/>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried using your xslt 2.0 and its working fine but then I realized that I needed to have the common fields only. which means, in input file a if there is any consumerkey which is not present in the input file b then the output should not have that.

Comment: @zx485 thanks for your suggestion too. I have now remove the counter besides CONSUMERKEY_(position).

Comment: @2437850 I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: ok..Let me edit my question completely. as I was working on this and find out there could be some more things which could be added

Comment: @2437850 You should not make such broad changes after the question has been answered. In any case, yo need to simply copy the elements you want from the original file and from the lookup - for example, you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="Place | City"/>` to copy from the original and then use `<xsl:copy-of select="$details/*"/>` to copy all "fields" from the lookup.

Comment: yes I agree to you. I should have entered a new question instead. But thanks for your previous answer and help till now. Let me check with the suggested approach given by you.

Comment: @2437850 If you cannot make this work, post a new question with your best attempt. Meanwhile I will revert your question to the original.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k. I have posted a new question now with what my use case.  Also previous answered helped me to achieve what I wanted initially so I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192385/discussion-between-2437850-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: can you please guide me in my new question pls

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your objective with the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:variable name="bDoc" select="document('b.xml')/Details" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/ConsumerKeyperUsers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'CONSUMERKEY_')]">
        <xsl:variable name="keyValue" select="CONSUMERKEY/text()" />
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$bDoc/Detail[ConsumeyKey/text()=$keyValue]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConsumerKeyperUsers>
    <CONSUMERKEY_1>
        <Detail>
            <ConsumeyKey>QoChiX5FlNyqe1FuqU7VB2M</ConsumeyKey>
            <Place>Ocean</Place>
            <City>Urban</City>
        </Detail>
    </CONSUMERKEY_1>
    <CONSUMERKEY_2>
        <Detail>
            <ConsumeyKey>uzGjRVxnxmP00zrnZPtB9sM</ConsumeyKey>
            <Place>Road</Place>
            <City>Rural</City>
        </Detail>
    </CONSUMERKEY_2>
    <CONSUMERKEY_3>
        <Detail>
            <ConsumeyKey>RD37oO2jg4rlerxW5p6f76</ConsumeyKey>
            <Place>Plane</Place>
            <City>Semiurban</City>
        </Detail>
    </CONSUMERKEY_3>
</ConsumerKeyperUsers>
```

However, your naming scheme is less than optimal, because adding a number at the end of the `CONSUMERKEY_...` element is bad practice. You should refrain to `CONSUMERKEY` as a name for the elements instead. This would also simplify the templates needed to process this XML.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion too.. as you have suggested earlier, I have removed the naming scheme and restricted to name only